# multiple ros2 versions on same host using docker to avoid issues with arm64

Tags: ros2, docker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Beyond the issues of which ROS(2) versions are supported on which operating system, e.g. Ubuntu 18.04, 20.04 etc, I am finding that there are still ROS2 nodes that run on AMD64 but not ARM64, including so far as I can tell Intel librealsense.

On a Raspberry Pi or NVidia Jetson Xavier NX I can run Ubuntu 20.04 on ARM64, and ROS installs as expected.

When I try to install librealsense there is very little help, and everything seems to currently go back to Ubuntu 18.04 for ARM64, which doesn't let me use Foxy, Galactic etc.

So if I use a docker environment based on Ubuntu 18.04 I can network to the Ubuntu 20.04 host (which can be the main operating system or docker).  Hussarian do a lot of this for the Orbbec Astra, but they use ROS1 and ROSBridge.

If I run ROS2 Eloquent on the Ubuntu 18.04 docker image and install librealsense, does it matter that the rest of the system is on Ubuntu 20.04 and running Foxy or Galactic?

Or is it better (and why?) to run Melodic and ROS Bridge?

Many thanks if you can help!

Brian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402742/multiple-ros2-versions-on-same-host-using-docker-to-avoid-issues-with-arm64/) by [brianlmerritt](https://answers.ros.org/users/78477/brianlmerritt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2022-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've done more research and had support from DustyNV - basically CUDA support on docker is not viable between different Ubuntu OS releases.  It is probably possible to run Eloquent and Foxy on the same hardware using Docker, but definitely not using CUDA.

---

Originally posted by [brianlmerritt](https://answers.ros.org/users/78477/brianlmerritt/) with karma: 16 on 2022-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0